# Minimizing sum of functions under constrained domain

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

Consider this function, I am told to find minimum of it. I considered using lagrange multipliers but I have no constraint curves to work with.

Comment: There are inequality constraints for $x_1, x_2$, so Lagrange multipliers won't work here. You may check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Comment: I am very new to this..  I actually studied lagrange multipliers as a trick to questions from an mcq exam. I know some idea of partial derivative but I"m not so capable right now to digest that wiki article. If you sir can explain that article in simple terms, It would be of big help to me

Comment: The second constraint ensures the the terms under the roots are not negative. I would omit both constraints and then check if the optimal solution fulfill all conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using coordinate geometry:

You can think about $2$ points, $P$ and $Q$ having coordinates $(x_1, x_1^2/20)$ and $\left(x_2,\sqrt{(17-x_2)(x_2-13)}\right)$ respectively.

You're required to find the square of the minimum distance between them.

$P$ lies on the parabola $y=x^2/20$

And after a bit of simplification, you can see that $Q$ lies on the circle $(x-15)^2+y^2 = 4$

Now our problem changes to figuring out the shortest distance between a circle and a parabola.

The line of shortest distance between these curves must be normal to both of them; so it must pass through the centre of the circle, $(15, 0)$

And if the line intersects the parabola at $(h, h^2/20)$, it's slope must be $-10/h$

Using these conditions, we get the equation of the line to be
$$y = -\frac{10}{h}(x-15)$$
This passes through the point $(h, h^2/20)$ on the parabola, plugging this into the equation gives $h = 10$ as the only real solution.

The point on the parabola is then $A(10, 5)$ and that on the circle is $B(15-\sqrt2, \sqrt2)$

And the square of the distance between them is $2(5-\sqrt2)^2$

Comment: I"m confused as to how the circle equation came about

Comment: From the coordinates of point Q, $y = \sqrt{(17-x)(x-13)}$ simplify this to get the equation